# A primitive function of $ e^{x^{2}} $

Tags: integration, optimization

I made some efforts to set a closed form of primitive function of $ e^{x^{2}} $ i find

this  function  : $ f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}} $ where :

$f'(x)=(\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}})'$= $\frac{4x^{4}-4x^{2}-1}{4x^{4}-4x^{2}+1}e^{x^{2}}$

my question is : can I take $ f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}} $ as a primitive function

of $ e^{x^{2}} $ if $x$ hold a big values  ?

is there a function better then $ f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}} $ ?

thank you for any replies or any comments

Comment: One can imagine a situation in which this kind of estimate could be useful.

Comment: yes , i mean for exemple if x=200

Comment: This looks like an interesting asymptotic approximation.

Comment: ok, that's i want

Comment: is there a best function then this ?

Comment: It is known as the erfi function and directly related to the Dawson integral. Lookup these words. (Have a look at the continued fraction development on Wolfram).

Comment: ok, i know erf(x) , but it's not a closed form , then i deduced about it as a good approximation out (-1,1)

Comment: @rafik: You keep saying "....$x$ hold a great numbers", which means nothing in English. Please use expressions like "...when $x$ is big" (and its variants "...when $x$ is sufficiently big [very big, big enough]..."), instead. You can edit your posts to improve clarity

Comment: @André Nicolas, how i can use this interesting asymptotic approximation in complex anylesis ?

Comment: I do not see anything immediate. Very much not my field, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, there is "closed form" of $\int e^{x^2}$, at least in terms of a collection of "basic functions". Now, when you ask if it is a good approximation for an antiderivative for large $x$, the answer is that it depends! Note:
$$
\frac{4x^4 - 4x^2 - 1}{4x^4 - 4x^2 + 1} = 1 - \frac{2}{4x^4 - 4x^2 + 1} = 1 + O(x^{-4}).
$$
Now, as a ratio:
$$
\frac{\big(1+O(x^{-4})\big)\, e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2}} = 1+O(x^{-4}) \to 1 ~ \text{ as $x \to \infty$}. 
$$
However, as a difference
$$
\big(1+O(x^{-4})\big)\,e^{x^2} - e^{x^2} = O(x^{-4})\, e^{x^2} \to - \infty ~\text{ as $x \to \infty$}
$$
where we note that term $O(x^{-4})$ is negative. So, as a ratio, reasonably good; as  a difference, it seems reasonably bad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , then it's bad only in (-1,1)

Comment: no closed form existed since  :$\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\cdot\text{erfi}(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not a primitive of $e^{x^2}$ because $$f'(x) = \frac{e^{x^2}(4x^4-4x^2-1)}{(2x^2-1)^2}$$

which is not $e^{x^2}$.

In fact, $e^{x^2}$ does not have an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. For some notes on this topic, see [this talk by Martin Leslie](http://math.arizona.edu/~mleslie/files/integrationtalk.pdf).

Comment: thanks i know , just i mean for a great real numbers  of x

Comment: what is a "great real numbers of $x$"?

Comment: or i can i take it as approximative primitive if it's a good mathematics term ?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. Sure, since $f'/e^{x^2} \rightarrow 1$, the two are asymptotically the same. I don't know if this behavior is still true after integrating (i.e., I don't know if $f/\int e^{x^2} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: a Miller , the derivative of the function that i find is poor approximation in (-1,1) but out this area is approximatively to e^x² , for exemple x=10, it's derive near to e^x²

Comment: could u give me a function better then  $f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}}$ ?

Comment: @maik Miller , I would be interest if if find someone help me to use this approximation in complex analysis , thanks

Comment: @ maik Miller, I don't know how i could using this good asymptotic approximation in complex analysis ? and what's the difference between this approximation and error function ?

Answer (score 2):

> *thank you for any replies or any comments*

It can be proven, using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), that the anti–

derivative of $e^{x^n}$, with $n\in\mathbb N$, cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions for

$n\ge2$. Letting $n\in\mathbb Q$ , the case $n=\dfrac1m$ , with $m\in\mathbb N^*$, can also be added to the previous

list of exceptions. **However**, it can be expressed in terms of [special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions). Thus, for

$n=2$, it can be expressed in terms of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), $\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\cdot\text{erfi}(x)$, and

for other values of *n* in terms of the $($[incomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)$)$ [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\displaystyle\int e^{x^n}dx=\frac{(-1)^{^{-\tfrac1n}}}n~\cdot$

$\cdot~\Gamma\bigg(\frac1n,-x^n\bigg)$. Also, as far as definite integrals are concerned, we have the beautiful

identity $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx=\Big(\tfrac1n\Big)!=\Gamma\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)$.