# Find the Primitive of Complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

if it exists, find the primitive  of $\mathbb{e}^{z^2} $ on $\mathbb{C}$

How can I start the proof?

Comment: It doesn't exist. I advice you to stop looking for it. I'll try to link to a relevant page on this topic

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function will be helpful (with a small change of variables)

Comment: Thank you for that page, @bburGsamohT, that's probably as relevant as it's going to get. Also, this post is a possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830771/a-primitive-function-of-ex2) post

Comment: @vrugtehagel $e^{z^2}$ has a primitive on $\Bbb C$, because it is an entire function.

Comment: Allright, I'll give you that, but I read the question as if the OP wanted a closed-form, which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primitive of $\mathrm e^{z^2}$ exists and is named the [Faddeeva function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeeva_function).

But it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions (The four operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, and $/$, the functions $\ln$, $\exp$ and any combination between them functions). This result is a consequence of a [theorem by Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29).

Answer (score 1):

The primitive exist on $\mathbb {C}$ because it is holomorphic. Now take the path ( a line it's ok) that connect the origin with the point $z$, we say $\gamma (t)=tz$ with $t\in [0,1]$. Then $\int_{\gamma} e^{z^2} dz$ is a primitive.

Comment: Well.. no doubt.. But no closed formula can be given.