# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathop{}\! \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, dx$$

My first approach was to find the antiderivative but I can't seem to express it as I have not yet learnt about $\text{Si}(x)$. I then tried replacing the $\sin(x)$ with $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)$ but I just ended something even more complicated. Does making it go from $0$ to $\infty$ by multiplying by $2$ help?

Please help me in evaluating this integral.

By the way, I am familiar with substitution and integration by parts but not complex analysis or contour integration. However, if this question requires something I don't already know, I am willing to try and understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is well-known to be a tricky one (although classical). You most likely won't find the solution on your own. You can probably find solutions in undergrad courses, I don't know good references in english.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174072/integrating-functions-like-sin-x-x

Answer (score 14):

Here's an approach I enjoy; *maybe it's outwith the scope of your endeavour, so this may not pose as an appropriate answer*
notice
$$\int \limits_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x dy  = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx
&=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int \limits_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x dy \right)dx \\
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int \limits_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x dx \right)dy \qquad \text{(Change order of integration)} \\
&=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{-ye^{-xy}\sin x - e^{-xy}\cos x}{1+y^2} \right)\Biggr \rvert_0^\infty dy \qquad \text{(Integrate inner brackets by parts)} \\
&=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy \\
&= \pi
\end{align}

Comment: Good answer!! But... Fix it! xD Lots of minus signs are missing! lol

Comment: How do you justify changing the order of integration? Since $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_0^{+\infty} \lvert e^{-yx}\sin x\rvert\,dy\,dx = +\infty,$$ that's a delicate step.

Comment: @1over137 Whoops! Many thanks for your check - All $-\infty$'s present and correct!

Comment: @DanielFischer Great spot Daniel - I hope I'm correct in stating if you consider the strip $(0,a) \times (0,\infty)$ then observing that $\int_0^a \int_0^\infty  \lvert e^{-xy} \sin x\rvert dx dy \leq a$ then apply Fubini's theorem. To get the result I quoted, take the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @Kevin You can change the order first and then let $a\to \infty$. But new problem comes. You need to justify the interchange of $\lim_{a\to \infty}$ and the intergral sign.

Answer (score 8):

**1. If you are familiar with Dirac Delta**$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin(x) \over x}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left({1 \over 2}\,\int_{-1}^{1}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}kx}\,{\rm d}k\right)
\,{\rm d}x
=
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}{\rm d}k
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{\rm d}x \over 2\pi}\,{\rm e}^{{\rm i}kx}
=
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}{\rm d}k\,\delta(k) = \pi
$$

**2. Trick Calculus way**

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \; dx
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \; dx \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} \; dt \right) \; dx \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \sin x \, e^{-tx} \; dx dt \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2 + 1} \\
&= \vphantom{\int}2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi.
\end{align*}$$

**You would love also Feynman differentiation under the integral sign**

Comment: how do u justify the exchange of integrations in line one? i mean that is the only tricky part in this calculation

Comment: @tired I don't :D There is not so much rigor in that calculation, indeed I'm thinking that it's quite wrong.. even if it works..

Comment: ok i will help u out: for example u could use an exponential regulator $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_R dxe^{-\epsilon |x|}...$ and take the limit in the end

Comment: @tired Oh yes! This is what we do in QFT regularization processes, like to calculate self-energies! Haha here it is!  Thanks!

Comment: yeah i know, i am also part of this buisness

Comment: @tired Yay!! :D I find it so amusing. Even if sometimes I lose some details..